# Certificate for Android application

Tags: android

Trying to install application with ADB on physical device connected via USB:

```
adb -s ce06160684b99a0902 install  E:\D\android\MQTT\app\debug\app-debug.apk
```

Got error:

```
E:\D\android\MQTT\app\debug\app-debug.apk: 1 file pushed. 4.0 MB/s (3747450 bytes in 0.903s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]
```

I was generated application via `Build->Generate Signed Bundle/APK -> APK` and entered key data:

[image]

I suppose this procedure generates certificate? How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is trying to install `app-debug.apk` whereas the signed apk name is `app-release.apk` . What code are you using to install the apk to your device? Also try adding this certificate through

```
Project Structure -> Default Config -> Signing Config
```

For both debug and release if required.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation ([Sign your debug build](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#debug-mode)), you don't have to explicitly sign your `app-debug.apk`, it's done automatically. It uses a specific keystore, generated for you, under `$HOME/.android/debug.keystore`.

So you only need to click the play button, with your device selected in the drop-down list, as [described here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run).

You could also click on `Rebuild Project` instead of `Generate Signed Bundle / APK`, and manually upload it to device with your adb command.

Comment: In case I do simple build by clicking play button I get application running on my device and I get apk in my project directory  `c:\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk`. If I try tu install apk with APK I get message `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_TEST_ONLY: installPackageLI]`

Comment: You should use `Rebuild Project` instead of `Generate signed APK`.